# How to keep backup of our database in MySql

Tags: mysql

I want to keep backup of my database and import it into different System? and how to make .dmp
or store file in MySql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dump a database with the `mysqldump` command-line utility ; using a command like this :

```
mysqldump --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --host=ORIGIN_HOST DATABASE_NAME > backup.sql
```

Then, as the backup is just a bunch of SQL instruction, importing it to another database is as easy as using the `mysql` command-line utility :

```
mysql --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --host=DESTINATION_HOST NEW_DATABASE_NAME < backup.sql
```

And, as a couple of references to the relevant manual pages :

- [4.5.4. mysqldump  — A Database Backup Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)
- [4.5.1. mysql  — The MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html)
- and [Chapter 6. Backup and Recovery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-and-recovery.html)

Comment: From the mysqldump file you can restore the backup using:

    mysql --username=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --host=HOST < backup.sql

Answer (score 3):

Read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/backup-and-recovery.html). If there's something there that you're not sure about, ask a more specific question.